# apt-get tries to access ~/.config/git/

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, git

When installing new packages with the package manager, I get the permissions error shown below. This happens because `/home` is mounted from another server, however why is `apt-get`  trying to access `~/.config/git` in the first place?

```
(base) blk6@gho:~/$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libssl-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,846 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 [1,566 kB]
Fetched 1,566 kB in 3s (507 kB/s)       
warning: unable to access '/home/Users/blk6/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/home/Users/blk6/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
Selecting previously unselected package libssl-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 219434 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5) ...
warning: unable to access '/home/Users/blk6/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you running the command inside a conda virtual env (as suggested by the `(base)` prompt? Do you get the same issue outside of conda?

Comment: @steeldriver the issue persists even after deactivating the virtual env

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your package manager would try to invoke git, but you can try to use the [`strace`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/strace) utility to figure out what is going on. The strace traces system calls, including attempts to open files or executing programs.

To investigate your specific issue, I would try to figure out what commands are being executed (`-e execve`) by `apt-get` and its forked child processes (`-f`):

```
sudo strace -f -e execve apt-get install ...
```

If you remove the `-e execve` option, no filter will be applied, resulting in some lengthy output. To make strace write its output to a file, you can use the `-o file.txt` option before the command (e.g. `strace -f -o file.txt apt install ...`).

You can also use `-e execve -e file` to trace both command executions as well as attempts to open or read files. Then search for the invocation of the git command, and look for lines above this invocation. Perhaps that reveals a script name from which the command was invoked.

If that is still not sufficient, you could consider scanning the apt configuration in `/etc/apt/`. Perhaps you have configured it to invoke some hook. Example to look for invocations of git:

```
grep -nre git /etc/apt
```

The output will be empty if there are no matches, and display the file, line number, and line contents otherwise.